# One User get Forbidden 403 error in only one PC of all browser

Tags: authentication, browser, sharepoint-2013

One of my SharePoint site user get forbidden 403 error (site is opened but you have not permitted),In  this scenario there is only get **this error when access from only his PC(all browser)**, but while he access from **another pc it opened successfully**

**Tried solution:**

Default Browser: IE
Added in trusted site
Reset browser setting
Tick Prompt password every time

Comment: check in central admin first if site has become read only/locked.same for database also.

Comment: When IE reset default then site add in Local intranet and trusted site zone running successfully but after some time it **again get forbidden error**,It means some cache problem may occur any idea about this?

Comment: no I have checked site is not nither read only nor locked @Neel